# What is the problem for login Playfab with Game Center id?

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, playfab

in my game I'm trying to login Playfab with Game Center user ID.

```
Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate(
        (s)=> 
        {
            GameCenterUserName = Social.localUser.userName;
            GameCenterUsedID = Social.localUser.id;
        });
```

I use the code above, but it always returns GameCenterUsedID = "1000" and GameCenterUserName ="Lerpz". Can some help me about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need.
`PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithGameCenter`

The `Social` class are unity build-in side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did it. 
LoginWithGameCenterRequest req = new LoginWithGameCenterRequest { CreateAccount = true, TitleId = GeneralManager.inst.PLAYFAB_TITLE_ID, PlayerId = Social.localUser.id };
        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithGameCenter(req, DeviceIdLoginSuccess, PlayfabErrorScript); On Playfab side this works but when i check the Playfab users account, Gamecenter id = 1000.

Comment: Maybe it really is your valid GameCenterID. Are you using sandbox account?

Comment: In my tests i used my Game Center name. Then, I published my game with this. After publishing, I tried it on my friends iphone. When i run the game on my friend's phone, it showed my name again. This means that it also login Playfab with the same GameCenter ID with i used in tests. I could not understand what is going on.  Whether i use sandbox account or not, it should be different in any other ios device i think.

Comment: I have lookup some more and know that. id 1000 and user Lerpz is default value for Social.LocalUser. That mean the authentication never completed. Try log your parameter 's' to check the status.

Comment: Thanks razeo. I will try it now.

Comment: it is just a bool returns "True".

Comment: Can you try change Social.Active.localUser to Social.localUser. I'm not sure it affect anything through.